# SSIS Script Component as Source AddRow Null Exception

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis

I have a SSIS package with single Dataflow Task.  The first step in this Dataflow is a Script component setup as a source, the default 'Output 0' has been renamed to 'Out' and it has a single column 'UserID' of W_STR, length 11.  It is being routed to an OLEDB Destination table with a single column called [User ID] of type NVARCHAR(11).  The mappings are set.

When calling OutBuffer.AddRow() I get a Null Reference Exception.  I've deleted the script component and re-created it several times, removing all other logic to the point that the script component looks like this:

```
public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();
    /*
     * Add your code here
     */
}

/// <summary>
/// This method is called after all the rows have passed through this component.
///
/// You can delete this method if you don't need to do anything here.
/// </summary>
public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();
    /*
     * Add your code here
     */
}

public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    /*
      Add rows by calling the AddRow method on the member variable named "<Output Name>Buffer".
      For example, call MyOutputBuffer.AddRow() if your output was named "MyOutput".
    */
    OutBuffer.AddRow();
    OutBuffer.UserID = "1234567";
}
```

Yet still it fails on AddRow()...  I'm using SQL Server Data Tools 2015 with my project in package deployment mode and the target SQL version set to SQL 2012.

```
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer.AddRow()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptBuffer.AddRow()
   at OutBuffer.AddRow() in c:\Users\oka2bbf\AppData\Local\Temp\Vsta\a20c6c234a834b8e924d02b641c4b06d\BufferWrapper.cs:line 45
   at ScriptMain.CreateNewOutputRows() in c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Vsta\a20c6c234a834b8e924d02b641c4b06d\main.cs:line 111
   at UserComponent.PrimeOutput(Int32 Outputs, Int32[] OutputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] Buffers, OutputNameMap OutputMap) in c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Vsta\a20c6c234a834b8e924d02b641c4b06d\ComponentWrapper.cs:line 49
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PrimeOutput(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)
```

---

**Edit: If I change the project to SQL 2014 or SQL 2016 it works.  It seems to be an issue with SQL 2012, however I'm deploying to SQL 2012, so I need to have it set for SQL 2012.  I have Development Edition of SQL 2012 installed (the only SQL instance I have installed locally) and as I'm using SQL Server Data Tools 2015 to edit the package.**

Comment: Is it complaining about the insert? Check table for nulls and primary key insert. If its complaining about the select i would limit the input to rows you know are good to try and eliminate source data issues.

Comment: Table it's attempting to insert into is a heap and has no rows.

Comment: do you still get the error if you don't try and insert to the destination and just have it go to a rowcount component? (I have a vague recollection that errors in other parts of the flow can cause this type of confusing error)

Comment: @MartinSmith I remove the OLEDB Destination, added a Row Count destination and created a variable to use with the Row Count.  I still receive the Null Exception error when AddRow is called...

Comment: While not a true answer - someone else had the same problem here and decided to use SSDT for VS2012 - -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458772/ssis-targetserverversion-causes-null-rows-in-script-component